# Creating Jenkins Process Job DSL. Interface doesn't show DSL Script box

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Jenkins from https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins. After creating my user and adding the DSL plugin, when I try to create a DSL script the interface does not show the code box.

[image]

I have tried to run the docker image attaching a volume so I can use file system files... but I also didn't manage to make that work either... I'm running out of ideas on how to proceed. All the references that I used show the DSL script box after the installation without a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had something similar happen to me. This text area seems a bit buggy, for me it was always collapsed. There is a handle in the middle which allows you to change the box size. If you can't see it then this might be a different problem (maybe some browser plugin?).

Also might try clicking between `Use the provided DSL script` and `Look on Filesystem`, I vaguely remember this handle showed up after I did that. Sometimes just saving the job (with the JOB DSL step added to the job) helps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A similar issue happened to me, it is happening in the newer versions.
I installed an old version of Jenkins - that old version didn't have this problem

Answer (score 1):

That's definitely a bug, as a workaround what you can do is via HTML set a high of the box.

1. right click on the line, then inspect (I'm using chrome)
   [image]
2. on the div change the value from 0 to any desired value. (I set 200 for this example)
   [image]
3. Right after that the box will appear.
   [image: List item]

hope it helps